# fail2ban regular expression for asterisk 19

Tags: regex, fail2ban

I have an asterisk server that is attacked. There is a fail2ban jail for the asterisk logs but the configuration does not pick up the this situation:

```
[2023-07-27 11:25:57] NOTICE[152571] res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.c: Request 'REGISTER' from '"213" <sip:213@54.36.115.125>' failed for '185.210.157.40:5977' (callid: 1048704493) - Failed to authenticate
[2023-07-27 11:25:57] NOTICE[152571] res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.c: Request 'REGISTER' from '"322" <sip:322@54.36.115.125>' failed for '185.210.157.40:5803' (callid: 522785130) - No matching endpoint found after 35 tries in 0.182 ms
[2023-07-27 11:25:57] NOTICE[152571] res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.c: Request 'REGISTER' from '"322" <sip:322@54.36.115.125>' failed for '185.210.157.40:5803' (callid: 522785130) - Failed to authenticate
[2023-07-27 11:25:57] NOTICE[152570] res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.c: Request 'REGISTER' from '"322" <sip:322@54.36.115.125>' failed for '185.210.157.40:5803' (callid: 1616436563) - No matching endpoint found after 36 tries in 0.187 ms
[2023-07-27 11:25:57] NOTICE[152570] res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.c: Request 'REGISTER' from '"322" <sip:322@54.36.115.125>' failed for '185.210.157.40:5803' (callid: 1616436563) - Failed to authenticate
[2023-07-27 11:25:57] NOTICE[152570] res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.c: Request 'REGISTER' from '"213" <sip:213@54.36.115.125>' failed for '185.210.157.40:5977' (callid: 2926631629) - No matching endpoint found after 37 tries in 0.199 ms
[2023-07-27 11:25:57] NOTICE[152570] res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.c: Request 'REGISTER' from '"213" <sip:213@54.36.115.125>' failed for '185.210.157.40:5977' (callid: 2926631629) - Failed to authenticate
[2023-07-27 11:25:57] NOTICE[152571] res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.c: Request 'REGISTER' from '"212" <sip:212@54.36.115.125>' failed for '185.210.157.40:5677' (callid: 2397138656) - No matching endpoint found after 38 tries in 0.200 ms
[2023-07-27 11:25:57] NOTICE[152571] res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.c: Request 'REGISTER' from '"212" <sip:212@54.36.115.125>' failed for '185.210.157.40:5677' (callid: 2397138656) - Failed to authenticate
```

/etc/fail2ban/asterisk-security.conf :

```
[INCLUDES]

[Definition]

failregex = SECURITY.* SecurityEvent="FailedACL".*RemoteAddress="[^"]*/[^"]*/(<HOST>)/[^"]*".*
            SECURITY.* SecurityEvent="InvalidAccountID".*RemoteAddress="[^"]*/[^"]*/(<HOST>)/[^"]*".*
            SECURITY.* SecurityEvent="ChallengeResponseFailed".*RemoteAddress="[^"]*/[^"]*/(<HOST>)/[^"]*".*
            SECURITY.* SecurityEvent="InvalidPassword".*RemoteAddress="[^"]*/[^"]*/(<HOST>)/[^"]*".*

ignoreregex =
```

My understanding of regular expression is poor and I would be very thankful if someone could help with the failregex definition in order to detect this attack!

Comment: What is it you want to match exactly? Please also provide examples of input you *don't* want to match.

Comment: which of those `failregex` do you think would match the example data?  I don't see one that matches

Comment: @Bohemian - I want to match the ending part, I tried this but doesn't work: failed for '<HOST>:.*' \(callid: \d+\) - Failed to authenticate

Comment: @erik258 - The present failregex is the current configuration of fail2ban which does not catch those cases. I only need to mark the 185.210.157.40 as <HOST> to identify the attacking ip address and to verify for exemple for "Failed to authenticate" in order to match the case.

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Your regexes have terms like `FailedACL` but that doesn't appear in the sample input. Please show some sample input, some of which should not match and some that should, with a variety of edge cases and tell us why some should match and why some should not and indicate *exactly* what parts you want captured as a group (name `HOST`?).

Comment: @bohemian - thanks a lot for your further concern. I discovered right now that in the default installation of fail2ban there is an asterisk filter that does what I need! Thanks again for your helpfulness

Answer (score 1):

Finally found out that fail2ban is delivered with an asterisk filter that does all I need. (/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/asterisk.conf)
So I just had to use this one.